# Graph of convex and strictly convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

how does a plot of a convex function look like, when comparing to a strictly convex function?

Thanks & sorry for the stupid q!

Comment: The plot of a convex function can have some straight bits (straight lines)

Comment: What thoughts do you have? Any ideas on the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the domain is an interval containing more than one point and $f$ is a convex function defined on that interval. 
Then $f$ is strictly convex if and only if the graph contains no straight line segment.

(As an aside for specialists, and this is messed up in some text books even, the indicator function of a singleton is actually strictly convex!)